# Exec format error when compiling in nfs shared directory inside a VM

Tags: c, linux, gcc, virtual-machine, nfs

I set up a 32 bits Debian VM on my host 64 bits OS. I shared the source code directory using NFS.

When I compile inside that shared folder, I am unable to run the executable:

```
nicolas@vdeb32:~/Shared$ cc hello.c -o hello
nicolas@vdeb32:~/Shared$ ./hello
-bash: ./hello: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
nicolas@vdeb32:~/Shared$ file hello
hello: data
```

But when the output is out of that shared folder, everything works fine:

```
nicolas@vdeb32:~/Shared$ cc hello.c -o /tmp/hello
nicolas@vdeb32:~/Shared$ /tmp/hello
hello
nicolas@vdeb32:~/Shared$ file /tmp/hello
/tmp/hello: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32
```

What is the cause of that behavior? I found that [askubuntu reply](https://askubuntu.com/a/697757/628976) but there is no explanation and anyway my host is not running windows neither my executable is a link.

Thanks.

[EDIT] I found the reason why the file cannot be executed. Editing hello.c, I noticed that the file, once saved, was only contaning zeros:

```
nicolas@vdeb32 ~/Shared $ xxd hello.c 
00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000                      ........
```

After some retries: when creating a file, everything works fine. But when I edit a file (in the shared directory), it is overwritten with zeros (same number of bytes as the original file). When compiling, the executable produced contains also only zeros. I am left with a different problem but the same question: what is the cause of that behavior?

[EDIT2] No trouble with the same architecture when the guest is running Mint 64 bits.

Comment: Are you compiling on the same system you are running on? Or you are compiling on the host when trying to run on VM (or vise-versa)? In the latter case you need to *cross-compile*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am indeed compiling on the same machine I am trying to execute the output (the guest).

Comment: Make sure you don't have some `cc` locally in that folder.

Comment: I'd be very curious whether the resulting executable differs (in terms of cmp or diff) in the NFS dir vs in /tmp.  Check to make sure that your nfs share is not mounted noexec, but I don't think that will change the file output

Comment: @EugeneSh. No I don't. Even if I had, I am compiling from the same folder. Only the output directory differs.

Comment: Then I will second what @SamHartman said. Check `exportfs` output.

Comment: @SamHartman The two files differ. Here are the mounting options in /etc/fstab: defaults,user,exec,auto,noatime,intr

Comment: what `file` tells about the first one?

Comment: Nothing more than stated above: data :s

Comment: Weird one. Tried to delete it before recompiled?

Comment: Hum. Another clue. Let me edit the question, first.

Comment: Interesting edit. Is your host machine doing some funny stuff on the background?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, nice try. My shared folder is synced with nextcloud. I shutdown the client, restarted the VM, but same behavior. How could I find out if there is any "trigger" on my folder ? Thanks again.

Comment: What is happening to a file if you just copy it there? Is it becoming zeros again?

Comment: No. Copying is OK. But after editing it is zeroed. touch has no effect in this regard.

Comment: What are you using to edit? What if you use something else?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was using vim. I am not experiencing the issue using nano. This is weird.

Comment: And I guess vim is working fine in the other directories? Now it sounds like black magic.

Comment: Yes... I am about to give up. I think I am going to go for a walk and I will come back later on this. Now that I have a clearer idea of the culprit, it shall be easier. Thanks for your help, I will give you an update when I am done.

Comment: Maybe`/home` is on a filesytem that is mounted with the noexec-option?

Comment: You should probably move this to [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Debian Chroot's suck. Most of them are broken. I stopped using them because I wasted so much time trying to get them to work. I never could figure out what broke with their signing keys or how to fix it. Just setup a 32-bit VM and install the 32-bit OS. Here are some field notes, if interested: [Debian Chroot](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Debian_Chroot).

Comment: Yes, as stated this is my configuration: 32 bits VM running on 64 bits host OS. No chroot. I'm using qemu/KVM. I noticed some strange things with tcpdump (NFS paquets). I will investigate further tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Great! I eventually managed to solve the problem. This has nothing to do with compiling, editing or whatsoever. It was a network issue.

I tcpdumped NFS frames on both sides (btw that made me notice my NFS was using TCP -- I was sure UDP was the default).

**From the guest:**
[image: Guest]

- Data written is what was actually written
- Wrong TCP checksum

**From the host:**
[image: Host]

- Message zeroed
- TCP checksum OK

**Solution:**
I disabled offloading according to [that procedure](https://sokratisg.net/2012/04/01/udp-tcp-checksum-errors-from-tcpdump-nic-hardware-offloading/). I have still to understand the details, but at last I got something functional.

PS: The same behavior was happening when creating a file, but from the client side, as the file was not refreshed, everything was looking fine. But on the host, the same file was already zeroed.

Comment: Btw, what should I do with that question? Delete? Ask for closing? Amend?

Comment: Leave it. It is interesting... maybe should be migrated though, but it's not your concern.